# Vue.js Use method in v-for

Tags: javascript, loops, methods, vue.js

I want to run a method inside a v-for in my Vue component. 
Example:

```
<div v-for="(foo,index) in bar">
      <p>{{myMethod(foo,index)}}</p>
</div>
```

When I do this the p-tag just stays empty. Here is my method(with an axios call):

```
 myMethod:function(foo,index) {
    axios.get('/myAjaxCall')
    .then((response)=> {
        //works perfectly
        alert(response.data);
        return response.data;

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
   },
 }
```

When I `alert( SomethingWithFooAndIndex)`, the browser is showing exactly what I need. When I remove the axios call the method seems to work

Thanks!

Comment: you're missing a closing quote on the attribute btw

Comment: This is just a simplified example, I am using them in the ajax url

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you should use `myMethod` in `v-for`

[axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) is asynchronous

Try to do `myMethod` with `bar` in another method, get a data `newbar`, you can render the `newbar`

`<div v-for="(foo, index) in dataBar">
  <p>{{otherSimpleMethod(foo, index)}}</p>
 </div>`

1. add `dataBar` in data
2. do `myMethod` with variable `bar` in another method `newMethod`
3. update `dataBar`（the axios response） in `newMethod`
4. do `newMethod` in `mounted`(I guess you want to do this after page loaded)

Or you can try [nextTick](https://cn.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-nextTick-callback-context)

BTW, the title `Vue.js Use mounted in v-for` ??? maybe `Vue.js Use method in v-for`???

Answer (score 1):

You has issue in your code. You missed a quote 
`<div v-for="(foo,index) in bar">
      <p>{{myMethod(foo,index)}}</p>
</div>`

Please refer the following jsbin http://jsbin.com/wovavut/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You can still refer jsbin

Comment: Thanks to you I found out the axios is causing the problem. Chekc my edited question please

Answer (score 0):

I also don't believe you should use a method in the `v-for`, but instead use a computed property that applies your method to the unprocessed array of your items that likely sits somewhere in `data`:

[Vue.js 2: Computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Comment: But I need the foo from the for loop in my method. And I think you can't add variables to computed functions

Comment: @SanderVanKeer: if your data comes from somewhere (either set in created or as props) you can loop/map over that and save it (enriched with maybe data from an api call or user storage) to the computed property. Alternatively you can make the computed function do everything that you need done to the raw data and then iterate over it. Can you provide more context?